# Django Rest Framework : how to specify a serializer to use different fields to create, update and get

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a doubt with the serializers and so far I have not been able to solve it.  I explain the doubt with the following example:

I have a User model and this model has the following attributes: username, password, first_name, last_name, age, gender. I also have a serializer, which is called UserSerializer. The UserSerializer should do the following:

- When inserting information into the database, UserSerializer should only take into account the fields: username, password, first_name, last_name.
- When retrieving information from the database, UserSerializer should only take into account the fields: age, gender.
- When updating the database information, UserSerializer should only take into account the fields: password.

***My solution:***

```
class UserSerializer:

    class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    class UserGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['age', 'gender']

    class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['password']
```

***Question:***

The question: is there any way to synthesize the three serializers into one, or what is the best solution for this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `write_only` and `read_only` parameters in serializer fields to specify fields for creating and retrieving

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    age = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    gender = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'gender']
```

If any field is optional, then you can add the `required=False`

Comment: `required=False` is needed for fields `username`, `first_name` and `last_name` to enable updating User only with a password. This answer is not responding exactly to OP requirements though, especially:
> When updating the database information, UserSerializer should only take into account the fields: password.

Comment: I had already mentioned to add `required=False` for the optional fields. Anyway, updated the optional fields with the same.